# Use `operator const char*` in printf

Tags: c++

```
struct MyClass
{
    operator const char* ()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;  
    std::cout << obj;    // ok
    printf("%s\n", obj); // Crash
}
```

Why does object with `operator const char*` can not be automatically converted to `const char* string` in `printf` for mapping the `%s`?

Is it just because there is no type awareness in printf-like functions and `%s` only expect a array of char with terminal 0?

Comment: There should be a glowing sign in `C` tag. `C != C++`

Comment: No hard feelings, just a joke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why? Because of the limitations on variadic parameters in C++: they have essentially no type, you can think of them as `void *` (but they're not).

So knowing that, the compiler has no idea you think that should be a string. It could very well need to be an integer, or a double, or another object. Or just itself, which the compiler chooses.

Comment: But is the `%s` already give the hint so that it can treat the `void*` as a `const char*`?

Comment: No it doesn't, what functions do at run-time is of no consequence to the compiler or the language definition.

Comment: So the class type conversion is done in compile time but the compiler does not know what type it should convert in `printf`.

Comment: @ChenOT, The ellipsis is not typesafe at all. In order to get any of the arguments out, you have to know the exact type of what you're getting. It's unfortunate, but C++ has variadic templates, which are typesafe.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `printf` with:

```
printf("%s\n", obj);
```

the compiler does not use the auto conversion function to convert `obj` to `char const*`. `obj` is passed to `printf` by value and `printf` tries to treat that value as though it is `char const*`. As a consequence, your program exhibits undefined behavior. You'll have to explicitly cast `obj` to `char const*` to make your program behave predictably.

```
printf("%s\n", (char const*)obj);
```

If you turn on warning levels in your compiler, you'll probably see something to indicate that using `obj` in that `printf` call is not right. With `g++ -Wall`, I get:

```
socc.cc:16:23: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 2 has type ‘MyClass’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%s\n", obj); // Crash
```

Comment: Yeah I have saw the warning at VS2015.